I cannot get my script to print only the <TD> that matches TOOL01 and TOOL02
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from prettytable import PrettyTable

def find_sort_in_urls(url_list, custom_columns):
    for url in url_list:
        try:
            response = requests.get(url)
            soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
            p = PrettyTable()
            p.field_names = custom_columns

            for table in soup.find_all('table'):
                for row in table.find_all('<tr>'):    
                    cells = row.find_all('td')
                    if any('TOOL01' in cell.get_text() or 'TOOL02' in cell.get_text() for cell in cells):
                        p.add_row([td.get_text() for td in cells])                     
                          
            # Check if the table has any rows added, then print
            if p._rows:
                print(f'{p}\n')

        except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
            print(f"Error accessing {url}: {e}")

# List of URLs to check
urls = ["http://path/toolPM.php"]

# Custom column names
custom_columns = ["Location", "Entity", "Entity Type", "Weekly PM"]

find_sort_in_urls(urls, custom_columns)

input("Press ENTER to continue")

My script has no error and display nothing.  Not sure if my logic is correct

Maybe first use print() (and print(type(...)), print(len(...)), etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called "print debugging" and it helps to see what code is really doing.

you didn't add real URL so we can't check this page and we can't run - so we can't help you

if you don't get error then your logic is wrong, or html is different as you think. You should check what you get in response.text. Maybe server sends warning for hackers/spamers/scrapers or it sends Captcha.

I tried print(response.content) and got the html content as expected.  print(response.text) got same results but easier to read

then use print() to see other elements - step by step. What you get with print( soup.find_all('table') ) ? you could also use print( len(soup.find_all('table') )) to see how many elements you get. etc.

when I started writing previous comment and I started checking other elements which you should print then I saw find_all('<tr>')  - but it has to be find_all('tr') - remove < >. Probably if you would use print step-by-step then print( find_all('<tr>') ) would show you empty result, and you would know that there is some problem

The URL is internal URL  
LocationEntityEntity TypeWeekly PM

NewArea
TOOL01
Tester1
n/a


TOOL02
Tester2
n/a 
Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

add example HTML in question - it will be more readable. You could even add it directly in code - so we could simply copy and run it.

You have find_all('<tr>') but you need find_all('tr') without < >.
That could be all problem.

I changed find_all('') to find_all('tr') and got this error:  Row has incorrect number of values, (actual) 13409!=11 (expected)

now you have different problem and you should create new question on new page. Simply you have more mistakes in your code. But you didn't show URL so we can't run code to test all problems.

maybe you have to filter data before you use p.add_row([td.get_text() for td in cells]) but without HTML and working code I can't say more.
